# Google Maps V3 Multiple Markers from Addresses

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, street-address

I need to know that how to add multiple markers on google maps v3 from addresses. I am working on a website which has list of 10 businesses with their address per page and a map to locate them. I implimented a map for only one business but I need to know how to impliment for multiple addresses stored in variable named address1,...2,...3,...4. Following are my codes for one business:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Multiple Map</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
var map;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);    
var address = '52+E+20th+St, New+York, NY';
var address1 = '42+E+29th+St, New+York, NY';
var address3 = '56+W+25th+St, New+York, NY';
var address4 = '26+W+21th+St, New+York, NY';

geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
}); 
  }  
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:250px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently did roughly the same thing: in the below example, `r` contains a map center latitude and longitude, and a list of markers. Each marker has again a latitude and longitude, some text to show for the marker, and an index variable to use a different icon for each result.

Multiple markers are added by simply creating them, and giving the same `map` instance. The maps library is smart enough to show them all.

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(r.dest.lat, r.dest.lng);
var myOptions = { zoom: 14, center: latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

for (marker in r.markers)
{
    var m = r.markers[marker];
    var d = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(m.lat, m.lng),
                                     map: map,
                                     title: m.text,
                                     icon:"http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + m.l + ".png" });
}
```